# How to check if one value exists in an array?

Tags: solidity

I need to check if all the values in X array exist in Y array do something.
The order does not matter.

```
contract test {

    uint[] numbers1;
    uint[] numbers2;

    function push1(uint num1, uint num2, uint num3) public {
        numbers1.push(num1);
        numbers1.push(num2);
        numbers1.push(num3);
    }

    function push2(uint num1, uint num2, uint num3) public {
        numbers2.push(num1);
        numbers2.push(num2);
        numbers2.push(num3);
    }

}
```

How can I check all numbers in numbers1 exist in numbers2 or not?

Answer (score 11):

There are two approaches.

You can create a `view` function ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#view-functions)) that loops through the array and returns `true` if the item is found. Mind that a `view` function can be invoked using a gas-free read-only [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) instead of a (read-write) [transaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction) costing gas fees.

```
function exists1(uint num) public view returns (bool) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < numbers1.length; i++) {
        if (numbers1[i] == num) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This approach has a linear complexity. So if you need to validate the value existence during a transaction, it might be costly depending on the total amount of items in the array.

So there's a second approach - duplicate the values as keys of a `mapping` ([docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#mapping-types)) that can be accessed directly through its key. There's a constant complexity to search the value but it costs double to store the value.

```
uint[] numbers1;
mapping(uint => bool) public exists1; // default value for each key is false

function push1(uint num1, uint num2, uint num3) public {
    numbers1.push(num1);
    numbers1.push(num2);
    numbers1.push(num3);

    exists1[num1] = true;
    exists1[num2] = true;
    exists1[num3] = true;
}
```